# Gnuplot Range Factor of Number

Tags: gnuplot

For a lack of a better way to describe it, I want to apply a modulo to an rrange expression in Gnuplot 5.0 in order to ensure that the max is "rounded" to the nearest 10 units. I think that I'm on the right track, but am curious whether there is a more elegant method to accomplish this.  For example, this yields what I want:

```
max_range = int(STATS_max)

if (max_range == 0) {
    max_range = 1
}

while (max_range % 10 != 0) {
    max_range = (max_range + 1)
}
```

So, for example, a STATS_max value of 13.2 yields a max_range of 20.

Thanks in advance,
Dave

Comment: Just as a follow-up to @Christoph's excellent answer below. For my purposes, I still need to retain the code segment above that ensures that max_range does not equal zero. Applying ceil() to zero yields zero which, while accurate, is an illegal value for range max value. Error: "Can't plot with an empty y range!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First divide your `max_range` by 10, apply the `ceil` function (takes the next larger integer value) and multiply the result by 10:

```
max_range = ceil(STATS_max / 10.0) * 10.0
```

Comment: Brilliant.  Thanks very much Christoph!